# Storing test data for API tests using POJOs

Tags: java, testing, jackson, automated-tests, pojo

I have a quite big json file and I need to test the API using it with bunch of data. I implemented the serialized version of the request using builders approach with POJOs. Everything is ok, but I use strings in the setters method, so it is hard coded.

Lets say I have this example:

```
{
   "name" : "my_username",
   "first-name" : "My",
   "last-name" : "Username",
   "display-name" : "My Username",
   "email" : "user@example.test",
   "password" : {
      "value" : "my_password"
   },
   "active" : true
}
```

My question: What is the best practice to store test data for api tests?

Properties file? Csv/excel and parse it? still json and using object mapper to create the object?

We need to focus on the easy storage and modification for creating new test cases. My idea is to create a big objects, storing somewhere the test data and using getters, I can build any request/response objects easily and I can avoid any maintenance issues. Thanks!

Comment: Store as a JSON file, read into an Object via ObjectMapper.

Comment: I would have used a json-to-object library.  There are lots available.  The only reason imo to not do that would be because the tests are slow and need to be sped up.

Comment: My problem is if I want to rewrite the json file, it would be a huge work because I can have more than 100 items in it for 1 test case. In case of response, I can parse an excel to get all the data. What is the disadvantage of CSV?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it would be better to store the json files within the project. Or even AWS and pull these files in (you can check if they have been changed recently before pulling them in).

I have done something in the past where I store them in the project & do a full json comparison on a GET request of an API or use the file in order to do a POST.

POJO is a good way to create test data however you can end up with quite a few builders in your project & parsing from a file would be much quicker.

If you need a specific code example then let me know.

Comment: Code example would be appreciated.